# ArgumentError: message representative out of range when using the rsa gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am getting this error when trying to encrypt big messages. I wonder whether this is a limitation with rsa.rb or if I am doing something wrong. Did anyone bump against this error?

This is happening on the client side, where I am encrypting a huge message using the server's public key like this:

```
RSA::KeyPair.new(nil,server_public_key).encrypt(huge_base64_str)
```

This code blows up with the `ArgumentError: message representative out of range when using the rsa gem`

Comment: can you upvote my question now?

Comment: Why **should** I upvote your question?

Comment: Well, because it is well formed and because I need help... Whatever...

Comment: Using RSA to encrypt data is usually the wrong thing to do. With the most common padding scheme your data is required to be <= n - 11 bytes in length, where n is the length of the RSA modulus in bytes.

Comment: GregS: So what alternatives do I have, considering that using public key cryptography is a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do in this case is to encrypt the message with a symetric key (e.g. AES) and then encrypt the symetric key with rsa. and send the message and the encrypted symetric key.